# Can this method of finding related input fields be optimized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a script that needs to find hidden input values based on specific text within a column of the same row. I do not have control over the HTML.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw76aaqt/2/)

In this working fiddle, we must first find the last column that contains the text `'Year to Date'` (last column due to nested tables). Then we use a lot of jQuery to find a hidden input in the same row that contains the value `2.33333` we need.

The Javascript I wrote works but I see a lot of repetition and it seems very inefficient. Is there a way to optimize the determination of this group of variables?

```
var YTD = $('td:contains("Year to Date")').last().siblings().eq(7).find('input').val();
var EOY = $('td:contains("End-of-Year")').last().siblings().eq(7).find('input').val();
var qtr1 = $('td:contains("Quarter 1")').last().siblings().eq(7).find('input').val();
var qtr2 = $('td:contains("Quarter 2")').last().siblings().eq(7).find('input').val();
var qtr3 = $('td:contains("Quarter 3")').last().siblings().eq(7).find('input').val();
var qtr4 = $('td:contains("Quarter 4")').last().siblings().eq(7).find('input').val();
```

We cannot count on a pattern of id/name for the related input fields other than they will always occur in `eq(7)` related to the originating `td`.

Comment: can you change the html markup

Comment: Nope (see my first line) - I have no control over the HTML.

Comment: What about Table Header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  could extract it to a function, which will help with code reuse:

```
function findInputFromCellText(cellText) {
    return $('td:contains("' + cellText + '")')
             .last().siblings().eq(7).find("input").val();
}
```

Then you could do:

```
var vals = {
  YTD: findInputFromCellText("Year to Date"),
  EOY: findInputFromCellText("End-of-Year"),
  qtr1: findInputFromCellText("Quarter 1")
  /* So on */
};
```

Since the quarters seem to follow a pattern, you could do:

```
var vals = {
  YTD: findInputFromCellText("Year to Date"),
  EOY: findInputFromCellText("End-of-Year"),
  quarters: [1, 2, 3, 4].map(function(k) {
    return findInputFromCellText("Quarter " + k);
  })
};
```

You would then access `vals.YTD` or `vals.quarters[0]` etc.

Note that in the last example, `vals.quarter[0]` would be the *first* quarter and `vals.quarter[3]` would be the *last* quarter.

Now, if you want efficiency, you could easily do this:

```
var findInputFromCellText = (function() {
  var cache = {};
  return function(cellText) {
    if (cellText in cache) return cache[cellText].val();
    var result = $('td:contains("' + cellText + '")')
      .last().siblings().eq(7).find("input");
    cache[cellText] = result;
    return result.val();
  }
})();
```

Comment: I like your ``vals`` variable.

Comment: I had actually tried something very similar to your method, but it didn't seem to be more efficient (time/call wise). Maybe I should consider this approach, which IS code reuse efficient?

Comment: @Paul See my edit. You can cache results if you want more speed.